# Prevent BYES going through to next fixture round

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This takes winning players and places them in tblEntrants ready for the next round draw. It works fine but I need to add a to the CASE part something which will add Player1 or Player2 if the opponent being checked has a BYE..

Eg.. WHEN ResultPlayer2 > resultPLayer1 THEN Player2 OR (When players opponents name = "BYE" put the opposite player to the BYE through)

```
DELETE tblEntrants where compID=@compID
INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID, paid)
SELECT CASE WHEN ResultPlayer2 > resultPLayer1 THEN Player2 ELSE Player1 END, CompID, 'y'
FROM tblfixtures WHERE round=@round
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your expected results to make more sense -HTH ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DELETE tblEntrants where compID=@compID
INSERT INTO tblEntrants(AccountID,compID, paid)
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN Player1 ='BYE' THEN Player2
        WHEN Player2 ='BYE' THEN Player1
        WHEN ResultPlayer2 > ResultPlayer1 THEN Player2 
        ELSE Player1 END,
        CompID, 'y'
FROM tblfixtures WHERE round=@round
```

Comment: Many thanks, done the job. Simpler than I though, thank you.